# Correct the syntax

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I had to update a table i tried two queries but it shows syntax error can anyone help me pls I know this is basic but i am a begginer

```
String query = "Update masterusertable set username='" + txtName.Text + "',and set password='" + txtpassword.Text + "',and set phoneno='" + txtphoneno.Text + "',and set adress='" + rtxtAdress.Text + "' where userid ='" + txtuserid.Text + "'";

String query = "Update masterusertable set username='" + txtName.Text + "', password='" + txtpassword.Text + "', phoneno='" + txtphoneno.Text + "', adress='" + rtxtAdress.Text + "' where userid ='" + txtuserid.Text + "'";
```

anyother idea i had many big tables to be updated is it good to update using anyother ideas .

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Do youself a favour and go and search for "avoiding SQL injection"

Comment: Adding to @Matts comment - check up on parameterized queries. Not only will you avoid sql injection attachs, you will also optimize query plan reuse since you're not varying the queries with data.

Comment: The first update is not correct. The second one is better but if the column name is address (instead of adress) you will get the invalid column error. Please post the error message.

Answer (score 4):

This is wide open to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - you should change to [parameterized queries](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/10/24/2528.aspx).

As for the syntax of `UPDATE` there is only one `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE masterusertable 
SET
 username= @username,
 password= @password,
 phoneno= @phoneno,
 adress= @address 
WHERE userid = @userid
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use **AND** for all **SET** fields. Also no need to use **SET** multiple times You can just seperate them by ,.

```
update table set col1=val1,col2=val2.... where coln=valn
```

Comment: iAM USING ACESS AND AN OLEDB EXCEPTION IS OCCURING DUE SYNTAX ERROR IN UPDATE QUERY

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SET commands for each field you are updating. You just need the first SET command.

Try this:

```
String query = "Update masterusertable set username='" + txtName.Text + "',and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "',and phoneno='" + txtphoneno.Text + "',and adress='" + rtxtAdress.Text + "' where userid ='" + txtuserid.Text + "'";
```

Also, it would help to see the actual query being sent to SQL Server (if that's the DB you are using) and the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a string or a number for your primary key?
The `WHERE` part of the statement is formatting a string:

```
where userid ='" + txtuserid.Text + "'"
```

Is that what you want?

But since you say the problem is a syntax error, which this does not seem to have, I guess that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readability I would also recommend you using string.Format when concaterating the string..

```
String query = string.Format(
            "Update masterusertable set username='{0}', password='{1}', phoneno='{2}', adress='{3}' where userid ='{4}'",
            txtName.Text, 
            txtpassword.Text, 
            txtphoneno.Text, 
            rtxtAdress.Text, 
            txtuserid.Text
        );
```